# Cálculo de bytes de InputStream

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

He estado trabajando en la creación de una validación en ASP.NET para analizar los datos que vienen en una solicitud web, y no me ha quedado claro una acción que estoy realizando y me gustaría aclarar.

Cuando genero una solicitud web en la que subo un archivo cualquiera (una imagen por ejemplo), al analizar los datos `HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength` y `HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Length`, ambos me entregan el mismo valor, pero cuando intento calcular la cantidad de bytes de los datos `InputStream` a "mano" con la siguiente instrucción:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentEncoding.GetBytes(new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream, HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentEncoding).ReadToEnd())
```

me retorna un valor diferente a los 2 anteriores. Entiendo que esta tercera línea de código me debería retornar el mismo valor.

La codificación siempre me ha sido difícil de entender, pero en este punto no logro comprender qué estoy haciendo mal en el cálculo manual para obtener el mismo valor.